# EF Core : Must be reducable node

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am getting "Must be reducable node" error. I believe that Its a bug however I couldn't able to sort it out.

I am latest stable versions of DotNet Core, and using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.6. Also, I am using Devart.DAta.Oracle.EFCore v9.7.805.

```
public async Task<DomainResult<IEnumerable<InternalRiskDto>>> GetRiskByPeriod(int customerNumber, bool resultForGuarantor, int numberofPeriod, CancellationToken ctx = default)
{
    Expression<Func<InternalRiscData, InternalRiskDto>> selectorExpression = r => new InternalRiskDto
    {
        A12 = r.IrdA12 ?? 0,
        A1224 = r.IrdA1224 ?? 0,
        A24 = r.IrdA24 ?? 0,
        AccNo = r.IrdAccNo,
        Branch = r.IrdBranch,
        Fincode = r.IrdFincode,
        Frees = r.IrdFrees,
        Ftahak = r.IrdFtahak,
        Idno = r.IrdIdno,
        Limit = r.IrdLimit < r.IrdA12 + r.IrdA1224 + r.IrdA24 ? r.IrdA12 + r.IrdA1224 + r.IrdA24 : r.IrdLimit,
        Crmno = resultForGuarantor ? r.IrdKcrmno : r.IrdMcrmno,
        Risccode = r.IrdRisccode,
        Riscdate = r.IrdRiscdate,
        Riscode2 = r.IrdRiscode2,
        Rowid = r.IrdRowid
    };

    Expression<Func<InternalRiscData, bool>> crmPredicate = x => ((resultForGuarantor && x.IrdKcrmno == customerNumber) || (!resultForGuarantor && x.IrdMcrmno == customerNumber));

    var dateQueryable = _riskRepository.GetQueryable()
        .Where(crmPredicate)
        .Select(x => x.IrdRiscdate)
        .Distinct()
        .OrderByDescending(x => x)
        .Take(numberofPeriod);

    var dateList = await dateQueryable.ToListAsync(ctx);

    if (!dateList.Any())
        return _errorDescriber.NoRiskRecordFound(customerNumber, numberofPeriod);

    var result = _riskRepository.GetQueryable()
        .Where(crmPredicate)
        .Where(ris => dateQueryable.Any(x => ris.IrdRiscdate == x)) //Problem arises here
        .Select(selectorExpression)
        .Distinct()
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Riscdate).ThenBy(x => x.Risccode);

    return DomainResult<IEnumerable<InternalRiskDto>>.Success(await result.ToListAsync(ctx));
}
```

**UPDATE**

NumberOfPeriods is 5

StackTrace :

```
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ReduceAndCheck() 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ReduceExtensions() 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExtensionExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression expression) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteBinaryExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteLogicalBinaryExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpressionFreeTemps(Expression expression, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.Rewrite[T](Expression`1 lambda) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteLambdaExpression(Expression expr) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression expression) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.AddArguments(IArgumentProvider expressions) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMethodCallExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression expression) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.AddArguments(IArgumentProvider expressions) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMethodCallExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression expression) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.AddArguments(IArgumentProvider expressions) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMethodCallExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression expression) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.AddArguments(IArgumentProvider expressions) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMethodCallExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression expression) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.AddArguments(IArgumentProvider expressions) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMethodCallExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression expression) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.AddArguments(IArgumentProvider expressions) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMethodCallExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.Add(Expression expression) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.ChildRewriter.AddArguments(IArgumentProvider expressions) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteMethodCallExpression(Expression expr, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpression(Expression node, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.RewriteExpressionFreeTemps(Expression expression, Stack stack) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.StackSpiller.Rewrite[T](Expression`1 lambda) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile(LambdaExpression lambda) 
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Compile(Boolean preferInterpretation) 
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateExecutorLambda[TResults]() 
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateAsyncQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel queryModel) 
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler) 
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query) 
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() 
at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate_[TSource,TAccumulate,TResult](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 accumulator, Func`2 resultSelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\\a\\1\\s\\Ix.NET\\Source\\System.Interactive.Async\\Aggregate.cs:line 128 
at WestCore.AppCore.Services.PRisk.LocalRiskPlusService.GetRiskByPeriod(Int32 customerNumber, Boolean resultForGuarantor, Int32 numberofPeriod, CancellationToken ctx) in C:\\Users\\<username>\\Source\\Workspaces\\CoreBankingWorkspace\\WestCoreApiSS\\Main\\WestCore.AppCore\\Services\\PRisk\\LocalRiskPlusService.cs:line 104 
at WestCore.Api.WestCore.V1.Controllers.PRisk.RiskFeedbackController.Get(Int32 customerNumber, Boolean resultForGuarantor, Nullable`1 startDate, Nullable`1 endDate, Nullable`1 numberOfPeriods) in C:\\Users\\<username>\\Source\\Workspaces\\CoreBankingWorkspace\\WestCoreApiSS\\Main\\WestCore.Api\\WestCore\\V1\\Controllers\\PRisk\\RiskFeedbackController.cs:line 43 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments) 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync() 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync() 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context) 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync() 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter() 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context) 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync() 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync() 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) 
at WestCore.Infrastructure.Middlewares.ErrorHandlingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IHostingEnvironment env) in C:\\Users\\<username>\\Source\\Workspaces\\CoreBankingWorkspace\\WestCoreApiSS\\Main\\WestCore.Infrastructure\\Middlewares\\ErrorHandlingMiddleware.cs:line 32"
```

Comment: What is the value of : numberofPeriod

Comment: Question is updated accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately the exception stack trace just confirms that this is EF Core bug/issue. You could try replacing `.Where(ris => dateQueryable.Any(x => ris.IrdRiscdate == x))` with `.Where(ris => dateList.Contains(ris.IrdRiscdate))` and see if that fixes it. If not, please provide the relevant classes so we can reproduce (I've tried with similar query shape, but wasn't able to reproduce, so there must be something specific in your query/model which is triggering that bug).

Comment: Thank you @IvanStoev. Contains worked for me. It seems that Any cannot be evaluated as DB Query, thus EF Core tries to evaluate it locally but gets error due to a bug in EF Core. It would be nice If you can post your comment as answer so that I can mark it and upvote it for the community.

Comment: You are welcome mate, glad it helped. Please post it as self answer (for community benefits), my comment was just wild guess.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `Any` with `Contains` worked for me. It seems that `Any` cannot be evaluated as DB Query, thus EF Core tries to evaluate it locally but gets error due to a bug in EF Core.

```
var result = _riskRepository.GetQueryable()
    ...
    .Where(ris => dateQueryable.Any(x => ris.IrdRiscdate == x)) //Problem arises here
    ...;
```

is replaced by

```
var result = _riskRepository.GetQueryable()
    ...
    .Where(ris => dateList.Contains(ris.Riscdate))
    ...;
```

**For the Records: This bug will be fixed with EF Core Release 3.0**

*Special thanks to @IvanStoev*